# How to put locking at ArrayList item level in c#

Tags: c#, multithreading, collections, locking

I am trying to implement thread safe `ArrayList` Collection,

I want my collection should put lock at an item level instead of on complete collection.

Let say if my collection has 10 items, so 10 threads can update value simultaneously from index 1 to 10,  Since they are update different array item , so it should be allowed. Here update doesn't include removing an item from `ArrayList`

I don't want use in built concurrent collections, because of addition overhead.

Is there any locking mechanism available to put lock on individual  item of `ArrayList`.

Thanks

Comment: "I don't want use in built concurrent collections, because of addition overhead." => most probably, your own custom implementation based on `lock` will have a greater overhead...

Comment: Really: What @ken2k said.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use ReadOnly Collection
Or
ArrayList.IsSynchronized 
or
ArrayList.Synchronized

Comment: Synchronized ArrayList also put a lock on complete collection level, basically it just add extra locking step to every add, remove and other methods of collection.